# How to calculate positions on a z-axis

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, z-axis

[image: I drew a simple 3-coordinate graph in canvas below]

I drew a simple 3-coordinate graph in canvas above;

I defined a few constants to work with

```
var width = window.innerWidth * 0.5 , height = window.innerWidth * 0.5;
var cx = width / 2, cy = height / 2, cz = height / 2, blcx = 0, blcy = height, brcz = height, brcx = width, brcy = height;

var ySegment = height / 30;
var xSegment = width / 30; 
var xSegmentRatio = xSegment / width; 
var ySegmentRatio = ySegment / height;
```

cx and cy and cz all refer to the center of the canvas. `blcx` means bottom-left-corner-x, `brcy` is bottom-right-corner-y, etc. I realize this is a bit hack-ish, as this is the first attempt to do this, but if you bear with me, there is a real concept I am trying to grasp here.

and then drew the red lines like this:

```
(function() {
    var gridCx   = cx,       gridCy   = cy,        gridCz = cz;
    var gridBlCx = blcx,     gridBlCy = brcy;
    for (var i = cx; i < width; i++) {
        gridCx += xSegment;
        gridBlCx += ySegment;
        gridCzx -= gridCzx * (xSegmentRatio / ySegmentRatio);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(gridCx, cy);
        ctx.lineTo(gridBlCx, height);
        ctx.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
        ctx.stroke();
    }
})();
```

I tried this:

```
gridCzx -= gridCzx * xSegmentRatio;
gridCzy += gridCzy * ySegmentRatio;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(gridCzx, gridCzy);
ctx.lineTo(width, gridCzy);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
ctx.stroke();
```

and got this:

[image]

But I realized I am missing some fundamental mathematical concept. Thanks for any insight you can give!
My basic question here is: *How do I select a point on the z-axis given a distance away from the center?*

Comment: What is your question? Also, please explain the intuition behind your code. I can't make much sense of it. An explanation of your variables would help a lot for a start.

Comment: Sure, I updated the op. The intuition here is that I would like to define three axises, x/y/z, and since HTML5 canvas doesn't have a z-axis, I need to find a way to calculate a point on the z-axis I drew given a distance away from the center. The first thing I was trying to do was draw a grid on the z/y plane.

Comment: Check out canvas's built-in [skew transformations](http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/february/an-example-of-the-html5-canvas-transform-function.html)

Comment: My question is how do I select a point on the z-axis given a distance away from the center?

Comment: Use a [transformation matrix](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/) to skew a drawing and ALSO to find any transformed point in untransformed space. Here's a good [transformation matrix tool](https://github.com/epistemex/transformation-matrix-js)

Comment: Hmm, interesting method, but I don't see how it's relevant! I'll definitely take a look though.

Comment: Matrix math is the a common way of dealing with transformations. For example, you can (1) skew the matrix on the canvas, (2) draw your floor -- which will then look skewed like your example. Then to get a point relative to your center, apply the matrix to your desired [deltaX,deltaY] to get the corresponding [screen,screenY]. Time doesn't permit for a full answer, but you should definitely check out transformation matrices to accomplish your task. If you just want the math, check out the linked transformation library and all your math is there! :-)

Comment: Thanks again! Yeah, I definitely see how transformations could help with the end result, and if I was doing this for work or something I would definitely consider that. I am more interested in plotting points based on three coordinates, and I am positive there are formulas to deal with that or algorithmic solutions, I just need to find or realize them.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use transformation matrices, **if you just want the math**, look inside the [matrix script](https://github.com/epistemex/transformation-matrix-js). The math is all there! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Transforming 3 dimensions into 2 dimensions

**Axis tell us how to move**

To find a point in the first dimension x, move along the x axis, from left to right. To find a point in the second dimension y you must integrate both the first and second dimensions, thus 1st x from left to right, once you have that then 2nd along the y axis down the screen.

With each dimension you rely on the positioning of the previous dimension. It also relies on the axis, the x and y axis are at 90 deg to each other, but they could be at 45 or 120, it would not make any difference to finding 2D coords of a point. First along X axis then Y along the y axis.

**Vector functions**

Because the display is only 2D the axis can be represented as 2D vectors. The length of the vector tells the scale of the axis. Thus for the x axis if I define the axis as a 2D (display coords) vector (2,0) then I am saying that it goes 2 across and 0 down for each unit in the x coordinate. If I want to be at x coordinate 10 I multiply it by the axis to get the screen position.

Thus to the code...

```
function screenCoord(x,y){  // creates a coordinate in screen space
                            // screen space is always in pixels
                            // screen space always has the origin (0,0) at the top left
    return {
       x : x,
       y : y,
    }
}

function screenVector(x,y){ // a vector in screen space it points in a direction
                            // and its is in pixels 
    return {                // basically identical to the last function 
       x : x,
       y : y,
    }
}
```

So let's define the X axis that I had (2,0) scaled up by 2

```
var xAxis = screenVector(2,0);
```

Now a x position say 10

```
var xPos = 10
```

To find its location we need to get the screen coordinates along the x axis. We do that by multiplying xAxis by xPos. To make it easier we can create a vector multiply function

```
function multiply(vector, value){
     var x = vector.x * value; // multiply the vector x by value
     var y = vector.y * value; // multiply the vector y by value
     return screenCoord(x,y)
}
```

Now to find the first dimensional pos of xPos

```
var screenPos = multiply(xAxis, xPos); // returns the screen position of x = 10
```

Now to do the 2nd dimension we add that to the previous. Let's define a function to add a vector to another

```
function add(vector1, vector2){ // adds two vectors returning a new one
     var x = vector1.x + vector2.x;
     var y = vector1.y + vector2.y;
     return screenCoord(x,y);
}
```

So now lets create the y axis

```
var yAxis = new screenVector(0,2); // y goes down the screen and has no x change
```

and the y pos

```
var posY = 10;
```

So now lets do it from x

```
var screenPosX = multiply(xAxis,posX); // get the x position on the screen
var screenPosY = multiply(yAxis,posY); // get the y position on the screen
```

Now we add the results of the two coordinates

```
var screenXY = add(screenPosX,screenPosY);
```

And we have a coordinate on the screen of x = 10 and y = 10 (which in this case turns out to be at pixel location 20 across 20 down.

**The 3rd dimension**

Now it does not take much to guess what happens for the 3rd z dimension. For x along x axis, then y along the y axis and then z along the z axis

So define the z axis

```
var yAxis = new screenVector(1,-1); // z axis along the diagonal from bottom left to top right
```

Now the z coord

```
var posZ = 10;
```

So to find our 3d position, x along its axis, then add y along its and then add z along its axis

```
var screenPosX = multiply(xAxis,posX); // get the x position on the screen
var screenPosY = multiply(yAxis,posY); // get the y position on the screen
var screenPosZ = multiply(zAxis,posZ); // get the z position on the screen
```

need to add them together

```
var screenXY = add(screenPosX,screenPosY);
```

Then z

```
var screenXYZ = add(screenPosXY,screenPosZ);
```

and there you have how to do the conversion from one set of coordinates to another. It is called a transform

**The origin**

We are missing one last bit of information. The origin. This is where on the screen the the coords 0,0,0 (x,y,z) will be. It is the last part of the transform  and is in screen coords (x,y)

```
var origin = screenCoords(100,500); // set the origin at 100 pixels across 500 down
```

From the last calculation we got the screenXYZ coordinate in screen space, we need to add the origin to it

```
screenXYZ = add(screenXYZ ,origin);
```

Now you can draw the pixel at coordinates (10,10,10) (x,y,z) from the origin in on the 2d screen.

**The Matrix**

Hope that helps, if you understand that you have just learnt how to use a 3D transformation matrix. It holds the x,y,z axis as a set of three 2D directions, and the coordinates of the origin. The matrix does the very same functional steps, just it does it in a simple array that makes it more efficient and following some matrix rules allows very complex transforms. For example if you want to rotate, all you need to do is change the direction of the axies and you have rotated the object. To change the scale just change the length of the axis, to move the object just change the position of the origin.

Comment: This is an awesome post. Thank you! I need to study it a bit more and try to put it in play before I decide it it answered my question! This is the first exposure that I have had to vectors and vector space, so it may take me a bit of time.

Comment: Nice post on deltas / vectors. :-)

Comment: "Axis tell us how to move" -awesome.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, JavaScript's `Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` are super helpful in this scenario. The way I had to think about it was as if there were successive concentric circles with radiuses starting at my grid segment length and doubling for each succession. From there, I google a bit about how to find the point on a circle given a degree. It turns out circles, like triangles, have degrees, i.e. radians, and the one for the direction of my z-index is 5PI/4. Therefore, my function looks something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < zDistance; i++) {
    var r = xSegment * i;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.strokeStyle="white";
    ctx.stroke();
    var zRadian = {
        divided: function() {
            return 5 * Math.PI
        }, 
        divisor: function() {
            return 4;
        }
    }
    var zRadian = zRadian.divided() / zRadian.divisor();
    var x = cx + r * Math.cos(zRadian);
    var y = cy - r * Math.sin(zRadian);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillText('(' + x + ', ' + y + ')', x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]